# Spring OAuth2 + Http basic redirection with token

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm using OAuth2 Spring setup from [official spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_authserver) - full blown authorization server part.

There are two apps - separate authorization server with user resource server embedded and a client application - using JWT OAuth.

By default if you want to navigate to protected resource of the client app you get redirected to authorization server app where you can choose which authentication provider you'd like to use for the session. The problem is I want to support also local login mechanisms.

[image: login form]

I managed to introduce a simple login form which just gets from /user resource with Basic authentication which works fine except there is no redirection back to the resource which initiated the process in the first place and no JWT token is being issued.

Normally I would get redirected with JWT token but I guess basic authentication doesn't even have authentication success handlers not to mention *SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler* which *OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter* seems to be using after successfully logged in.

Here's my initial idea:

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        // .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/account/password/reset*/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .and().logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                // .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and().csrf().disable() // todo consider how to enable this only for parts of the service which is exposed to the web browser
                .addFilterBefore(createClientFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
    }
```

And somewhere at the end of the chain

```
val oldRedirectUrl = HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response).redirectUrl
        DefaultRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, oldRedirectUrl) // all those should be in authentication success handler for basic auth
```

The only problem is that once the user is authenticated at auth server (port 9998) and gets redirected to initial application (port 9999) he gets the following error:

[image]

The second time he does it (when he is already authenticated) it works fine. Read somewhere that the issue might be with apps stealing each others cookies so I renamed the cookies using

```
server:
  session:
    cookie:
      name: AUTH_SESSION
```

Config option. The resulting cookies (after authentication) under localhost domain are:

[image]

What is interesting AUTH_SESSION cookie changes its value after signing in.
Additionally I have no idea where JSESSION_ID came from. Maybe that's the problem here?

By the way it works perfectly when using formLogin auth.

Comment: Please provide some code what you have tried.

Comment: See the updated question